# Corda - gradle dependencies: compile, cordaCompile or cordapp?

Tags: gradle, corda

What is the difference between

- compile
- cordaCompile
- cordapp

For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
    cordapp project(":workflows")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**cordaCompile** indicate dependencies that should not be included in the CorDapp JAR. These configurations should be used for any Corda dependency (e.g. corda-core, corda-node) in order to prevent a dependency from being included twice (once in the CorDapp JAR and once in the Corda JARs).

**compile** indicates dependencies should be included with Cordapp.

**cordapp project** use this if the other CorDapp is defined in a module in the same project
,otherwise, cordapp "net.corda:another-cordapp:1.0"

Comment: So basically, `compile` dependencies are resolved at compile-time whereas `cordaCompile` and `cordapp` are resolved at runtime. What then are the logical differences between `cordaCompile` and `cordapp`, if both of them produce JARs that resolve dependencies at runtime?